# How to create dynamic folder tree structure in MVC using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0

This is a dynamic folder tree structure for those who recently shifted from normal ASP.Net to MVC version :
  I am not posting any question here, just giving a scenario and it's solution which could help someone... so please don't feel offended for this

The scenario is that I have some data in a table in database which is like a typical parent child table, a table that contain an unique ID and its parent Id which is also an ID of that table

like this :

```
MemberID                       UplineID
 admin                          self
 C1                             admin
 C2                             admin
 C3                             C1
 C4                             C2
```

so the tree will be like this for admin :

```
    C1
     |
      --- C3
    C2
     |
      --- C4
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question

Comment: yeah it's not a question I already mentioned that, I just felt i could share something that's why

Comment: I am aware of what you wrote, however if you reword it as a proper question, which you have answered below, you are less likely to have it closed/down-voted etc. The "question" as it stands is not useful (the answer is also not useful without detailed explanation). Sorry :)

Comment: sorry that i couldn't pleased you with my limited knowledge and I really don't care about closed/down-voted ... I am not here to play any online games.. its for those who are very new to mvc like me if they find it helpful and the answer is just another way to do it.. there should be many simple effective excellent alternatives

Comment: You need to watch your assumptions. I am certainly not here to play games *and they were not my down-votes*. I will place my own down-votes now as you ignored my simple advice to improve the question and/or the answer. They are "not useful" to anyone as they stand now. Sorry.

Comment: From the introduction page _Stack Overflow is a **question** and answer site_. [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/) or other similar sites are more appropriate for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what I did to achieve this :

This a store procedure :

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[getTreeStructureForMember]
(
   @uplineID nvarchar(50)
)
as
begin

    select * from Member_detail where SponsorID=@uplineID order by JoiningDate

end
```

In the controller:

```
    public ActionResult MemberTreeStructure()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public List<getTreeStructureForMember_Result> getTree(string MemberID)
    {
        var data = db.getTreeStructureForMember(MemberID).ToList();

        return data;
    }

    public JsonResult getTreeDownline(string MemberID)
    {
        var data = getTree(MemberID);

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In View :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnShow').click(function () {
        var memberid = $('#txtMemberID').val();
        if (memberid == '') {
            $('#txtMemberID').addClass('ErrorControl');
            return false;
        }

        $("#btnShow").css({ display: "none" });
        $("#loader").css({ display: "inline" });

        $.post('/Member/tree',
        {
            "MemberID": memberid
        },
        function (data, status) {


            $("#loader").css({ display: "none" });
            $("#btnShow").css({ display: "inline" });
            $("#result").html(data);

        });

    });

     $(document).on('click','.tree li.parent_li > span', function (e) {
            var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
            if (children.is(":visible")) {
                children.hide('fast');
                $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this tree').find(' > i').addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
            } else {
                children.show('fast');
                $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse this tree').find(' > i').addClass('icon-minus-sign').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
        }); 

});
 </script>

 <div class="table-section">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table-style">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            <input type="text" id="txtMemberID" class="textfield" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            <input type="button" value="Show" class="normal-button2" id="btnShow" />
            <img id="loader" src="../../Content/BlueOpal/loading.gif" style="display: none; vertical-align: bottom" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="result" class="tree">
</div>
```

and in the css :

```
  .tree
{
    /*min-height: 20px;*/
    height:auto;
    padding: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.tree li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 70px;
    padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.tree li::before, .tree li::after
{
    content: '';
    left: -36px;
    position: absolute;
    right: auto;
}
.tree li::before
{
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    bottom: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
}
.tree li::after
{
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    height: 20px;
    top: 25px;
    width: 41px;
}
.tree li span
{
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tree li.parent_li > span
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tree > ul > li::before, .tree > ul > li::after
{
    border: 0;
}
.tree li:last-child::before
{
    height: 30px;
}
.tree li.parent_li > span:hover, .tree li.parent_li > span:hover + ul li span
{
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
    color: #000;
}
.icon-minus-sign
{
        background: url(../Images/minusTree.png) no-repeat;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 6px 0 9px;
}
.icon-plus-sign
{
        background: url(../Images/plusTree.png) no-repeat;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 6px 0 9px;
}
```